# Bootstrap navbar on the iPad

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap-responsive.css file does a wonderful job of turning the navbar into a dropdown menu on the iPad.

My problem is that the Navbar is not fixed to the top of the screen.  Instead, it is honoring the padding-top on the body tag.

Q: Do I just add padding-top:0 to bootstrap-responsive.css?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of iOS? `position: fixed` doesn't work at all in earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: iOS 5.1 according to settings, general.

Comment: Have you modified any of the bootstrap code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include bootstrap.css, then your css, then bootstrap-responsive.css.

Answer (score 5):

after adding bootstrap.css,bootstrap-responsive.css. add this to the css file

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you including bootstrap-responsive.css after all other stylesheets? If you aren't, I'd suggest it, as I've had similar problems with Rails applications.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the margin tag isn't set so is falling back to the default (element.style), try setting `margin: 0;`. Alternatively it could be the position attribute isn't set, add `'position: fixed; top: 0;'`.